# Spyder Mac OS 10.10.5 Yosemite failed after updating anaconda using conda update anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, spyder

Well this is more of a tutorial than a question, as I was able to solve it after taking a few steps.

**First the problem**
I was installing  scikit-learn-intelex accelerators, and decided to update anaconda in Mac OS terminal with the usual `conda update anaconda`, and after running the command, and tried to launch Spyder to test the new module, I've got

> Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_intel_thread.1.dylib.

Answer (score 1):

**The solution**
These are the steps I took to solve my problem on Mac OS 10.10.5 Yosemite

1. Tried to revert(rollback) anaconda using `conda list –revisions` to a prior version, a nice feature when you don't want to uninstall anaconda but revert to a previous working version.
2. I did and tried all 5 versions I had installed, and it didn't work, if in your case that works, fine this is all you have to do. In my case it didn't so I same error after trying to run Spyder from the terminal, so I continued.
3. Try to **manually install the missing packages**, when you check your revisions, you'll notice some packages are missing and if you installed them back, sometimes the problem is solved, in my case it didn't.
4. Reinstall the Anaconda Navigator and try to manually upgrade Spyder from revisions. In the Anaconda `Navigator>Environments`, you can select individual packages, to update, I tried to update Spyder and Numpy, as the mkl library affects Numpy directly, sometimes this approach also works, and you are done, in my case I had to continue.
5. **Remove `anaconda3` from `/opt/`**. This is something radical but it worked! I removed the whole anaconda3 directory, by first positioning myself on `/myuser/opt/` and running `rm -rf anaconda3`, which is the command on the mac(Unix), and on Linux to remove a directory completely, so I did, and then proceeded to download a fresh package for OSX64 from anaconda.com, and install it in the default directory from scratch, for some reason, I CAN'T yes, *can't* open PyCharm(I tried multiple times using different Internet connections, a router or tethering from my iPhone, or even from an Android phone), from PyCharm, I always get a CORRUPT package! So I'm stuck and happy with Spyder, and I use other IDEs and Watson Studio.
6. The installed fresh anaconda package worked perfectly!Spyder launched fine so problem solved!